# AWS EMR spin up using Terraform is unable to copy jars under /usr/lib/spark/jars

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to spin up EMR cluster using Terraform. Cluster spins up successfully and all the settings are proper. I have a bootstrap_action as well in Terraform to copy spark/sqoop related jars from AWS S3 to /usr/lib/spark/jars/. Terraform is unable to copy jars as the Bootstrap_Actions starts in the beginning only before EMR creates /usr/lib/spark folder. Please let me if there is a way to achieve this ?

Comment: is the EMR cluster in a public or private subnet ? If private do you have a S3 endpoint gateway to the subnet? This is requested by EMR. Sorry if my question is so simple, more details would help dig deeper.

Comment: it's in private subnet........ Manually I can run aws s3 cp command.......